# how to set new date() in a @requestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to know if is possible to set a new date() in a @requestParam?

```
@RequestMapping("/resa")
public String reservation(Model model,@RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = ?????? )int p
) throws ParseException
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: No. Annotation values must be compile-time constants. And a Date can't be the default value for an int anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations in Java are limited to compile-time constants, so you can't instantiate any new Objects there. There may be a way by using Spring's Expression Language, but I find that hacky.

I guess after Java 8, the correct way to do this would be to have a parameter of type `Optional<LocalDateTime>>` (Date is a bad old API, don't use it):

```
@RequestMapping("/resa")
public String reservation(Model model,
       @RequestParam("date") Optional<LocalDateTime>> optionalDate){

    LocalDateTime date = optionalDate.orElseGet(()-> LocalDateTime.now());
}
```

The Spring docs explicitly mention [that Optionals are supported as arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments).

Comment: They say you shouldn’t use `Optional` for parameters, it⁄s (mostly) for return values. See for example [Java 8 Optional: How to Use it](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-how-use-it), the section *How should Optional NOT be used?* near the bottom: “it won't buy us anything … in input parameters of methods”. (But I agree in using `java.time`, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can make it unrequired, and then just check whether it's null and then assign it with new Date()